# Image does not upload to database. ValueError. The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm working on a project (simple social media site). Logged in users should create posts with text and image.

When I submit the form, the image does not uploads and a ValueError occurs, saying that "The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it."

The only way to attach an image to the post is from admin panel, but that's not what I want to do.

I think there's a problem in views.py - I saw many posts, where this is done by using Function Based Views, but I didn't manage to find a solution with Class Based Views.

I'm pretty new to Django and most probably I'm missing something small (or at least I hope so).

Could you have a look and advise how to proceed. Any help will be much appreciated!

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics/', null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py - CBV for creating a post

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: In the form do you have    enctype="multipart/form-data"
Something like 
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Could you show your template for this view? Just to make sure that you have the `enctype` set correctly in your HTML form tag (as Damini pointed out in his comment).

Comment: Wow. I did not expect it to be that simple...Thank you!!!

Comment: I will just add that as the answer so you can vote and close it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enctype in your form like

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

> Image does not upload to database.

Please, don't do this. 
There are several serious constraints you should keep in mind:

If you are storing static data (images/videos/etc) to some folder on the backend's storage you will probably encounter in problem, when you will need one more back-end server. Very probable that this folder would need to be covered by some kind of filesystem replication.

If you are storing static data right to the database - it might be even worse. Relational databases are not designed for huge binary traffic, and you will really fast run out into the performance degrade.

The recommended way is to store this kind of content **directly to some CDN**. It is littlebit harder to implement, but in mid. perspective it is the most efficient way. This would lid to efficient static content delivering, good caching, efficient traffic distribution (less traffic to you front servers == better performance), and finally would keep your database tiny and fast.